# Excel formula - getting mapping details from 2 sheets of the same work book

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Please can you help me with the below excel formula?

Sheet1:

- Col A = Business use case number (BUC001, BUC002...)
- Col B = Business use case definition corresponding to the Business use case number
- Col C = Covered by Requirement Number = (VA001, VA002...)

Sheet2:

- Col A = Requirement ID (VA001, VA002, VA003...)
- Col B = Requirement Description corresponding to Requirement ID

I want to map the `Sheet1:Col A` data into `Sheet2:Col C` such that `Sheet2:Col C` has the details of the Business use case number exercised by the corresponding `Sheet2:Col A = Requirement ID`

Comment: You might want to consider [using database software like Access](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/using-access-or-excel-to-manage-your-data-HA001042918.aspx) if you want to get relational views of your data.

Answer (score 1):

If your data looks like this:

```
Sheet 1
A           B         C
BUC001  Buc1 blah   VA001
BUC002  Buc2 blah   VA002
BUC003  Buc3 blah   VA003
BUC004  Buc4 Blah   VA004
```

and

```
Sheet 2
A         B         
VA001   VA1 Blah
VA002   VA2 Blah
VA003   VA3 Blah
VA004   VA4 Blah
```

And you want sheet 2 Col C to read Sheet 1 Col B by matching VA###, you can use a [vlookup](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx), but you will need to rework sheet 1 to look like this:

```
Sheet 1
  A        B         C
VA001   BUC001   Buc1 blah
VA002   BUC002   Buc2 blah
VA003   BUC003   Buc3 blah
VA004   BUC004   Buc4 Blah
```

and use formula in sheet 2 column C `=vlookup(A1,sheet1!$A$1:$C$4,3,false` But you must replace `$C$4` with the last cell in column C that has data. This will match the `VA###` in `sheet 2 col A` to the `VA###` in `sheet 1 col A` and return the `Buc# blah` from `sheet 1 col C`